# curl subprocess data in header

Tags: python, unix, curl, header

In python I am running a curl command

```
subprocess.check_output('curl ...')
```

and the process returns data in the header (not body), how can I capture this using subprocess?

```
curl ... > file
```

does not work either

Update

I have now tried *requests* which can read headers but it does not get the header from the 302 redirect.

Comment: Do you mean HTML header and body? There shouldn't be any difference in how curl returns them. It's just a long text on stdout. And what do you mean by capture? Do you want to have the output of the process available in a python variable?

Comment: it's not really HTML but text transfer, yes available in a python variable

Answer (score 2):

### Save to filename.txt

```
import subprocess

with open('filename.txt', 'wb') as f:
    subprocess.call(['curl', '-I', 'http://stackoverflow.com'], stdout=f)
```

### Get header to a variable

```
import subprocess

header, status = subprocess.Popen(['curl', '-I', 'http://stackoverflow.com'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print header # string
```

### Using requests

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com')
print r.headers # dictionary
```